# How do I apply these same CSS rules to JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, rotation

I am building a site, I want the background img to stretch to 100% height x width of browser, and also to alternate random images upon refreshing; I currently understand how to make one img stretch using a div and just using CSS, I also understand how to alternate different images using JS (I know nothing about JS, I googled this). The problem is, I do not know how to apply CSS rules to JS, I only know how to apply them to HTML.  Can someone please tell me how to apply these same rules of CSS to the JS? I will post the CSS, the DIV (containing one background img), and the JS (with alternating images, but no CSS rules) below for clarification. I would really value your guys' input! Thanks!

```
<div id="background">
<img src="images/2.jpg" class="stretch" alt="#" /></div>

#background{
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
position: fixed; 
left: 0px; 
top: 0px; 
z-index: -1; 
}

.stretch {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

<script type = "text/javascript">
    <!--
    document.write("<img src= \""+Math.floor(1+Math.random()*5)+".jpg\"/>");
    //-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following javascript.(You will need to write one line for each propert)

```
document.getElementById("background").style.width= "100%"
```

Comment: where do I include that into the script? Is there a specific place?

Comment: just add it into the '<script>' tag. Also please mark it as the answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The better way to apply all CSS rules is to include all the rules in a class and then add the class to the element using Js.

```
<div id="background">
<img src="images/2.jpg" alt="#" id="stretch" /></div>

.background{
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
position: fixed; 
left: 0px; 
top: 0px; 
z-index: -1; 
}

.stretch {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

<script type = "text/javascript">

    document.write("<img src= \""+Math.floor(1+Math.random()*5)+".jpg\"/>");
    document.getElementById("background").setAttribute("class", "background");
    document.getElementById("stretch").setAttribute("class", "stretch");

</script>
```